# antivmdetection/vmcloak/VBoxHardenedLoader what's the deference for anti virtualbox detection?

Tags: virtualization

There are softwares that can detect virtual machine and stop running. I want to find a way for anti detection.

I searched and found there are some scripts on github for this purpose, they are

```
antivmdetection https://github.com/nsmfoo/antivmdetection  
vmcloak https://github.com/jbremer/vmcloak/  
VBoxHardenedLoader https://github.com/hfiref0x/VBoxHardenedLoader
```

I don't know what's the difference between them, and the antivmdetection and vmcloak looks quite similar... I want a virtual machine to look like as real as possible (like real dmi information), but I don't know which one to choose just based on their description.

Since their setup process will take a lot of steps. I haven't found any article online explain their differences. Does anyone know what's the differences among them?